# SaltStack nodegroups with more than one host results in an error

Tags: salt-stack

First the facts:

- Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
- salt-master 2016.3.3 (Boron)
- salt-minion 2016.3.3 (Boron)

I tried to use nodegroups as described [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/nodegroups.html).

```
nodegroups:
  web: 'salt-master1,salt-master2'
```

If I run ...

```
salt -N web test.ping
```

... it results in:

```
No minions matched the target. No command was sent, no jid was assigned.
ERROR: No return received
```

Changed my nodegroup to:

```
nodegroups:
  web: 'salt-master1'
```

Voila ...

```
salt-minion1:
True
```

I also tried the other notations to define a nodegroup as described in the linked documentation.

How i get it work with more than one host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognized my fault.

Did not realize the L@ notation is explicit for a list of hosts.

Solution for interesting people:

```
nodegroups:
  web: 'L@salt-master1,salt-master2'
```

results in:

```
salt-minion1:
True
salt-minion2:
True
```